# MongoHub remove data

Tags: mongodb

Looked everywhere online and can't find a simple answer to how to delete an id from MongoDB using MongoHUB.

In MongoHub I click on remove and i get presented with this above the query box:

```
db.site.markets.remove()
```

i want to remove this data:

```
{
  "_id": 10,
  "item": "box",
  "qty": 20
}
```

Surely this code should work?

```
db.site.markets.remove(item : 'box' )
```

or

```
db.site.markets.remove(_id : 10)
```

Both of them don't work.

I'm making this too difficult... Stupid though it may sound a right click, delete function would be helpful...

Comment: `db.site.markets.remove({ _id: 10})` should remove the document with the `_id` set to `10`. I suspect you need to use valid JSON syntax with MongoHUB, like is necessary with the MongoDB console: [remove](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/).

Answer (score 1):

When removing using mongohub you must wrap the parameters in quotes.

```
{"item" : "box"}
```

Also when removing by mongodb built in id the `ObjectId()` function is also required.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "12345")}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should give an object to mongodb. And _id column generated by mongodb is type of ObjectId, so you should use ObjectId("10") when passing the parameter as below:

```
db.site.markets.remove({item : 'box'})

db.site.markets.remove({_id : ObjectId('10')})
```